# Getting current values in delegated class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have done a delegate , so in the class delegated, which is a UIPopover, there is a method that received an object of my PreguntasViewController. If i print the variables , there is not anything. Why could it be? Thanks.

```
// -- PreguntasViewController

- (void)getRespuestasDelegate {
    [delegate getRespuestas:self];
}


//Delegated class

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    PreguntasViewController *preguntasViewCotroller = [[PreguntasViewController alloc] init];
    preguntasViewCotroller.delegate = self;
    [preguntasViewCotroller getRespuestasDelegate];

}

- (void)getRespuestas:(PreguntasViewController *)preguntasViewController{
    for(NSString *respuesta in preguntasViewController.preguntasArray) {
        NSLog(@"%@", respuesta);
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", [preguntasViewController.preguntasArray count]);
    NSLog(@"%@", preguntasViewController.ayudapreguntas);
}
```

Comment: what _does_ the logs show? what _should_ the log show?

Comment: The values in PreguntasViewController before calling to UIPopoverController

Comment: it is not quite an answer to my question...

Comment: Sorry. Now the log shows 0 and null . It should show the values before calling the UIPopoverController.

Comment: _before_ you call your delegate method back, the values are valid? where do the values lose itself? what is the point _after_ you don't have the values anymore? what does your log say during the debug session?

Comment: I receive a new object, so for this reason are the initial values. Is it possible to recover the before values?

Comment: somewhere your datas are lost. I don't see your code, you have to find out the critical point of it, using the debug session. it can help you to discover what happens exactly. there would be many reasons, e.g. the `ARC` deallocated an object, because you forget to keep it alive... etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me from your example like you are allocating an instance of PreguntasViewController and then immediately calling its getRespuestasDelegate method. I don't see anywhere that preguntasArray gets populated. Is it populated as part of the PreguntasViewController's init method? If not, I wouldn't expect there to be anything in the array.

Comment: But i am using a UIPopoverController, when it receives the object, it should't contain the value of the variables before calling to UIPopover?